# C# Bitcoin class - Create unique btc address for each order - make deposit & withdraw

Tags: c#, library

I am looking for a good library in c# for bitcoin as payment method in my web site.

My purposes from this library :

1. Create unique btc address for each order
2. deposit job with callback url
3. withdraw job

Is there any library for that purpose?
Or should i use a third party api?

> I am using visual studio 2015 & i am in .net 4.8 & i want to use that
> library in asp.net.

Comment: Check [NBitcoin](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin) and [NBXplorer](https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer) although I am not sure about .NET 4.8. If possible use .NET 6 and Visual Studio 2022 to avoid issues.

Comment: I checked NBitcoin - It is working with .Net 4.8.
But there is no samples on it about my three purposes.

Comment: For send btc i found this [Link](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43625/how-can-i-send-bitcoin-using-c-and-the-nbitcoin-library) - What about deposit with callback url & create unique btc address for each order?

Comment: You can ask questions in https://gitter.im/MetacoSA/NBitcoin